# Is 2-coloring in NL or L?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, complexity-classes, colorings

The 2-coloring problem is in P.  How can I prove that it is in NL or L? I see that I should create a deterministic/nondeterministic algorithm with logarithmic space, but I have no idea how to store the coloring in logarithmic space.

Answer (score 5):

The 2-coloring problem is [$\mathsf{SL}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL_(complexity))-complete. That means that there is a logspace reduction from 2-coloring to undirected accessibility (and conversely). See [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00001603) for some references.

It was showed in 2004 that [$\mathsf{L} = \mathsf{SL}$](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1391289.1391291).

Answer (score 3):

Note that a graph $G$ is 2-colorable iff $G$ is bipartite iff $G$ has no odd cycle. All these equivalences are well-known and can be easily looked up. Using that, it is easy to show that the language is in $NL$, and one can even show that it is in $L$, as already answered [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/79887/is-deciding-whether-or-not-a-graph-is-bipartite-in-l).